# For an integrable function $f$, do continuity conditions on its integral affect continuity of $f$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

In this question, whenever I say "integrable" I mean "Riemann-integrable".

The (first) fundamental theorem of calculus states:

if $f\in C[a,b]$, then the function $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)\, dt$ is continuous in $[a,b]$, differentiable in $(a,b)$ and $F'(x)=f(x)$ in $(a,b)$.

Now, a (sort of?) converse would read:

if $f$ is an integrable function in $[a,b]$ such that the function $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)\, dt$ is $C^1[a,b]$, then $f$ is continuous.

This is not true, as the answers below put it, it suffices to alter a continuous function on a point, which does not alter the $C^1$-ness of its integral.

Now I ask this: are these *all* the counterexamples? Does there exist a counterexample which is not of this kind, i.e. a continuous function save for a removable discontinuity?

To clarify: a function $f:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$ is said to have a *removable discontinuity* in a point $c\in [a,b]$ if both one-sided limits (or the one that is defined, in case of $a$ or $b$) exist and are equal.

Comment: What about $f(x)=0$ for $x \neq 0$ while $f(0)=1$, with the interval being $[-1,1]$?

Comment: That was easy. How silly of me. Then I ask this: is there a counterexample with no removable discontinuities?

Comment: @Bruno: I wasn't sure what you meant by "removable discontinuity".

Comment: @Eric: Shai Covo's answer below made me realize your example was correct, actually, because in a removable disctontinuity (i.e. a point in which the one-sided limits exist and are equal) what matters is topology and not measure, so producing a function which is discontinuous in a null set, we can take the null set to be dense, and then produce a counterexample which does not consist of removable discontinuities. Can't you "undelete" the answer? I'll clarify the meaning of removable discontinuity on the original post.

Comment: @Bruno Stonek: The way described above is not the only one, there are examples with a single non-removable discontinuity.

Comment: @user6312: yes, like Thomae's function but instead of altering the zero function on every rational, alter it on the set $\{\frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{1}{n}:n>2\}$

Comment: @Bruno Stronek: Or else start with functions which are $1$ on very rapidly shrinking intervals around $1/n$ and $0$ elsewhere.  Then eliminate all discontinuities except the one at $0$ by "rounding" using $C^\infty$ functions in the usual way.

Comment: @Bruno: I mistakenly approved an edit that changed your question. A bit too much I rolled it back to your last version. I liked the other title but I overlooked the addition. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**Edit:** I understood integrability in the Lebesgue sense. The longer first  part is the original answer.

---

I'm rearranging my answer since I'm a bit confused about the actual question, which seems to be:

> If $F(t) = \int_{a}^{t} f(x)\,dx$ is a $C^1$-function, is it then true that $f$ is continuous?

The answer to that question is *no*, since we can always modify $f$ on a null set without changing $F$. The characteristic function of $\mathbb{Q}$, for example, is *nowhere continuous* but its integral is zero over every interval. These are true discontinuities, not only removable ones.

The point is that $f$ is completely underdetermined in this question. *Any* modification of $f$ on a null set will yield the same $F$, thus we can't hope for more than $F' = f$ almost everywhere. Amazingly enough, this turns out to be true.

The right question to ask was answered by Lebesgue. The starting point is that for an integrable function $f$ its definite integral $F$ will always be [absolutely continuous](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity). The [Lebesgue differentiation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem) even tells us that $F$ is almost everywhere differentiable and $F' = f$ almost everywhere.

Lebesgue proved even more:

> Assume that $F$ is differentiable almost everywhere. In order for $F$ to be the definite integral of its derivative it is necessary and sufficient that $F$ be absolutely continuous.

This is proved in any decent text on measure theory e.g. Royden or Rudin.

On the other hand, [Luzin's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lusin's_theorem) implies that a measurable $f$ *is* continuous on the complement on a set of arbitrarily small measure.

One further point you should be aware of: If $F$ is continuous and differentiable almost everywhere and $F' = 0$ wherever it is defined then $F$ can be non-constant, even monotonic. the standard example for this is called the Cantor-Lebesgue function, or more colorfully [the devil's staircase](http://ioannis.virtualcomposer2000.com/math/cantor.html).

Finally, I'd like to point out that it is an [awfully subtle business](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66462/which-functions-of-one-variable-are-derivatives) to characterize the functions which are derivatives of everywhere differentiable functions.

---

**Added:**

Robert Israel left the following comment to this answer (thank you very much for that!):

> According to Lebesgue's criterion, a function is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ if [and only if] it is continuous almost everywhere and bounded. To maintain the continuity almost everywhere in the counterexample, the set on which you modify $f$ can be a closed set of measure $0$, e.g. a [Cantor set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor_set).

The only thing I'd like to add to that is:

> [*Lebesgue's criterion is actually Riemann's criterion*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/39922/riemann-integral-question/39970#39970)

see *Über die Darstellbarkeit einer Funktion durch eine trigonometrische Reihe* (1854). More precisely, the relevant passage is Section 5 on pages 226 and 227 of Bernhard Riemann's *[Gesammelte mathematische Werke und wissenschaftlicher Nachlass](http://www.archive.org/details/bernardrgesamm00riemrich)*.

(Hat tip to Roy Smith and Pete L. Clark)

Comment: @Theo: I definitely did confuse the two.

Comment: @Theo: I don't understand your sentence on absolute continuity. Also, I don't quite see how it is related to this problem, especially since the wikipedia link talks about Lebesgue integrability; could you please elaborate? Thank you!

Comment: @Bruno: That's the best I can do at the moment. If there are things that remain unclear, please ask. I'll address them in a few hours.

Comment: Another thing which is unclear in the question is if integrable means Lebesque or Riemann, that makes a big difference for the construction of the example....

Comment: @user9176: edited to clarify. @Theo: thank you for a very detailed and informative answer!

Comment: @Bruno: You're welcome. Thanks for the clarification of your question. Unfortunately, I understood "integrable" in the Lebesgue sense. I'll add something on the Riemann integrable case a bit later.

Comment: According to Lebesgue's criterion, a function is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$ if it is continuous almost everywhere and bounded.  To maintain the continuity almost everywhere in the counterexample, the set on which you modify $f$ can be a closed set of measure 0, e.g. a Cantor set.

Comment: @Robert: Thank you very much for this (this made updating this answer very easy) and correcting the annoying typo!

Comment: @Bruno: Thanks for accepting this answer before I actually updated it, I hope you like the addition.

Answer (score 3):

The actual conclusion is that $f$ is equal almost everywhere (i.e. except on a set of Lebesgue measure 0) to a continuous function, namely $F'$.

Answer (score 2):

Counterexample: Define $f$ by $f(x)=0$ if $x \in [0,c)$, $f(c)=1$, $f(x)=0$ if $x \in (c,b]$. Then $f$ is integrable, not continuous, and $F$ is identically zero (hence, in particular, smooth).

EDIT: As an interesting counterexample, let $f$ be the function considered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7004/continuity-of-function).

Elaborating: The function $f$ defined in the above link is continuous on $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$ (i.e., the irrationals) and discontinuous on $\mathbb{Q}$ (i.e., the rationals). Since $f$ is zero on $\mathbb{R}-\mathbb{Q}$, $F$ is identically zero (in particular, smooth). So this is a counterexample with $f$ being discontinuous on a dense set and, moreover, Riemann integrable.

EDIT (more details). The aforementioned function is known as [Thomae's function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomae%27s_function). For convenience, consider its restriction to $[0,1]$ (still denoted $f$). Since $f$ is bounded on $[0,1]$ and its set of discontinuities (is countable and hence) has measure $0$, $f$ is Riemann integrable. The fact that its integral $F(x)=\int_0^x {f(t)\,dt}$ is identically zero on $[0,1]$ is clear from the picture (given in the Wikipedia link). This also follows from the fact that if a function is (proper) Riemann integrable then it is also Lebesgue integrable and both integrals coincide; indeed the latter can be computed as follows:
$$
\int_{[0,x]} {f(t)\,dt}  = \int_{[0,x] - \mathbb{Q}} {f(t)\,dt}  + \int_{[0,x] \cap \mathbb{Q}} {f(t)\,dt}  = \int_{[0,x] - \mathbb{Q}} {0\,dt} + 0 = 0,
$$
since $[0,x] \cap \mathbb{Q}$ has measure $0$. This (standard) example of $f$ is particularly appropriate here, because $f$ is discontinuous on a dense subset of its domain.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **"no"**.

Take any continuous function $f$, and then alter its values on some null set.  Then it can have uncountably many discontinuities, and the integral equality will still hold.  (Since it was a null set)

Answer (score 1):

A nice but different sort of converse appears in Henstock-Kurzweil integration theory:

If $F$ is continuous on $[a,b]$ and differentiable on $(a,b)$, then the derivative $f=F'$ is necessarily Henstock-Kurzweil integrable on $[a,b]$ and $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t)\,dt$ for all $x$ in $[a,b]$.

This theorem is remarkably easy to prove, also. A nice source for this is a recent book by [Yee and Vyborny](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521779685).

Answer (score 0):

This is not true. Consider a constant function on some interval $[a,b]$, with a single removable discontinuity at some point. This is integrable and it's $\int_a^x f(t) dt$ is continuous.