# What are the differences among the different definitions of an integral?

Tags: integration

For a non-mathematician (physicist) all the integrals and definitions are equal so what are the differences among:

- The Lebesgue integral
- The Riemann Integral
- The Riemann-Stiejles integral

Why aren't all the same?

Comment: Related: [Lebesgue integral basics](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7436/lebesgue-integral-basics)

Comment: For a physicist all functions are continuous (or left continuous, or right continuous) at all but finitely many points of singularity. Well, if you consider only those functions, then integrals are just all the same. Differences of these types of integrals occur when you consider "bad" functions.

Comment: [This](http://www.mast.queensu.ca/~andrew/notes/pdf/2007c.pdf) is a nice exposition of some of the differences between the Lebesgue and Riemann integrals. It might also be worth noting that there are other theories of integration: [Henstock-Kurzweil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henstock–Kurzweil_integral), [Choquet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Choquet_integral), etc. Admittedly, alternative definitions are tend to just be generalisations, but so are Riemann-Stieltjes and Lebesgue, in a sense.

Comment: http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/98/comparison-of-different-concepts-of-integral

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1497662/how-much-do-we-really-care-about-riemann-integration-compared-to-lebesgue-integr http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/53121/how-do-people-apply-the-lebesgue-integration-theory

Answer (score 6):

First of all, the definitions are not *same*, not even nearly same. The *Riemann-Stieltjes integral* is a *generalized* version of the *Riemann integral*, which is a basic foundation and is useful for many practical situations. But there are still functions which are not *integrable* under Riemann's definition or even in the modified setup established by Stieltjes. The *Lebesgue integral* supersedes the previous integrals in the sense that it deals with a lot of functions that are not Riemann/Riemann-Stieltjes integrable, but the two integrals coincides when they both exist.

Comment: With some small caveats: Riemann integrable does imply Lebesgue integrable, but there are [some](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/67198/does-int-0-infty-frac-sin-xxdx-have-an-improper-riemann-integral-or) improper Riemann integrals which are not Lebesgue integrable.

Comment: This answer might suggest that the point of the Lebesgue integral is just to extend the amount of integrable functions. It isn't https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_integration#Limitations_of_the_Riemann_integral